# Issue with Ajax POST in Firefox and Chrome but not IE8

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem with the following code. 
When I run it in IE8, I get an alert when I have a successful return from the call.

This does not happen in Firefox and Chrome, i.e. I get no alert when running it there. 
Everything else works, except that it seems to me like the code section which is supposed to execute once the call is successful fails.

```
function stuffFile(file, wfid) {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

    var url = "http://someotherserver.page.aspx";
    var params = "fileName=" + file + "&param11=" + wfid;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        //alert('onready');
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var response = jQuery.trim(xmlhttp.responseText);
            alert('response ' + response);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(params);


}
```

Comment: Works for me in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/wGeAY/ (just changed url/params) probably something elsewhere. You obviously have jQuery in your stack, why not use its simple ajax functionality?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it with the console?

Comment: The problem is that the url is on another domain. Firefox does not allow that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using jQuery, you should use its [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) capabilities. It takes care of creating the `XMLHTTPRequest` object and all the differences between different browsers, and does a lot of the stuff you are doing manually.